# return values from multiple matching rows

Tags: excel

First off, I'd like to do this *without* VB if possible, so I don't have to go through the hassle of teaching recipients how to enable macros.

Now, I believe what I'd like to do is simple, but the answer may be complex formula-wise. I'm trying to list out in new columns the values from a specified column in rows which have matching values from two *other* columns. Sounds tricky I'm sure, but an example should help immensely...

Say I have the following data:

```
 ------------------
| sts | pos  | bye |
 ------------------
| 0   | QB   | 8   |
| 2   | WR   | 3   |
| 2   | QB   | 10  |
| 0   | QB   | 4   |
| 2   | QB   | 7   |
| 0   | WR   | 11  |
| 2   | WR   | 9   |
| 2   | QB   | 5   |
 ------------------
```

That's my source. I want to list out the `bye` value from all rows that have `sts = 2`, for each respective `pos`. In other words, from the source data above I'd want to see the following result set:

```
 --------------------------
| pos | byes               |
 --------------------------
| QB  | 10  | 7  | 5  |    |
| WR  | 3   | 9  |    |    |
 --------------------------
```

...because those are the `bye` values in the rows with `sts = 2` and `pos` equal to the corresponding `pos` in the result table.

Again, I'd like to avoid macros if possible, and just use a formula in the `bye` cells of the results table.

Hopefully that makes enough sense for you to take a stab at it. Thanks!

### FOLLOW-UP:

@Richard-Morgan I attempted to use your formula but can't get it to work. Here is a screenshot of my actual spreadsheet so we can use real cell references:

[image: spreadsheet snapshot]

So `sts` is `B2:B303`, `pos` is `D2:D303`, and `bye` is `E2:E303`. So then I'd like to list out the byes in columns `U` thru `Y`. It looks like your answer, if I'm smart enough to implement it, will get me what I need, so any assistance you can provide to get me to the finish line is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I presume you also can't use pivottables?

Comment: I choose not to because appearance is important with this, and is more easily customized without the overhead of pivot tables (at least in my experience).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured out a way to get my desired results. It isn't the cleanest or best way, but it achieves my goal of listing the results horizontally, and avoids macros or pivot tables.

I use a hidden worksheet to list out all the `pos` and `sts` values, concatenated as a single value. So...

```
sts   | pos   | bye
----------------------
2     | QB    | 8
2     | RB    | 5
2     | QB    | 11
0     | WR    | 7
. . .
```

...becomes....

```
     D   | E
    -----------
5  | 2QB | 8
6  | 2RB | 5
7  | 2QB | 11
8  | 0WR | 7
     . . .
```

Then, I have a "shadow" results area that mimics the results area on my front-page worksheet. It looks like so:

```
     G   | H   | I   | J   | K
    -----------------------------
5  | QB  |     |     |     |     |
6  | RB  |     |     |     |     |
7  | WR  |     |     |     |     | . . .
```

In **H5:H7**, I have the following formula:

```
=IFERROR((ADDRESS(MATCH("2"&$G5,$D$5:$D$305,0)+4,COLUMN($E5),4)),"")
```

This returns the first cell reference it finds in the concatenated column that starts with **2** and ends with the value in column **G** (e.g. the formulas in row 5 are looking for **"2QB"**).

Then, in **I5:***n***7** I have the following modified formula:

```
=IFERROR(ADDRESS(MATCH("2"&$G5,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDIRECT(H5))+1,4)&":$d$"&MAX(305,ROW(INDIRECT(H5))+1)),0)+ROW(INDIRECT(H5)),COLUMN($E5),4),"")
```

The reason I modify the subsequent columns is to change the range in which the formula is looking for its value to start at the next row *after* the previously found value. For example, with the data above, the formula in **H5** would look for "2QB" in D5:D*n*, and return the first row it finds and attach it to column E, which would be **E5**.

The formula in **I5** would then look for "2QB" starting in D**6** instead of D5, a row *after* the row referenced in H5's result.

Hopefully that made sense.

So what I end up with in my hidden worksheet is this:

```
     G   | H   | I   | J   | K
    -----------------------------
5  | QB  | E5  | E7  |     |     |
6  | RB  | E6  |     |     |     |
7  | WR  |     |     |     |     | . . .
```

Then, on my front page worksheet, I simply get the values (the `bye`) referenced by the cells in H5:*n*7 using:

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT(lookups!H5),"")
```

...which gives me my final result:

```
     G   | H   | I   | J   | K
    -----------------------------
5  | QB  | 8   | 11  |     |     |
6  | RB  | 5   |     |     |     |
7  | WR  |     |     |     |     | . . .
```

Like I said, it's totally convoluted, but it works, and I can always refine it later if I figure out how. :)  Thanks to you who took a swing at this seemingly complex problem for me! I'm sure your answers work beautifully as well.

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of the following could be used:

```
{=INDEX(tbl, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(G$3, $A$2:$A$9)
 *COUNTIF(G$4, $B$2:$B$9), ROW(tbl)-MIN(ROW(tbl))+1), ROW($C1)), COLUMN($C1))}
```

where the A column is sts, B column is pos, and C column is bye.  The variable tbl is the range of data (not the headers).  G$3 would be the sts filter and G$4 is the pos filter.

Copy the array formula DOWN to find all the matching byes; #NUM! will appear after finding no more matches.  If this bothers your users, you can add an ISERROR or a tricky conditional format that makes the text white on white.

You can then copy over the formula to the next column and enter new filter values.

```
            G   H
sts Search  2   2
pos Search  QB  WR

            10  3
            7   9
            5   #NUM!
            #NUM!#NUM!
```

If your users are comfortable with pivot tables, using them would be much easier, I would think.

**EDIT**
Making the formula "transpose" is a bit tricky and I am not having any breakthrough on how to fix that.  However, if you want to manually edit the column formulas, here is what you want.

(I made the assumption that S is the sts filter.  Maybe you're just doing a count there, but I didn't see where you enter the filter for sts.  If S isn't the sts filter, update the formulas to point to where sts is 2 or whatever.)

U2:

```
{=INDEX(tbl, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($S2, $B$2:$B$303)*COUNTIF($R2, $D$2:$D$303), 
 ROW(tbl)-MIN(ROW(tbl))+1), ROW($D$1)), COLUMN($D$1))}
```

V2:

```
{=INDEX(tbl, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($S2, $B$2:$B$303)*COUNTIF($R2, $D$2:$D$303), 
ROW(tbl)-MIN(ROW(tbl))+1), ROW($D$2)), COLUMN($D$2))}
```

etc.

This allows the cells to be copied down.

I am sure there is a way to INDIRECT the ROW/COLUMN, but I ran out of time to look at this at the moment.

**EDIT 2**
If you put a simple number increment somewhere, let's say U1 has 1, V1 has 2, W1 has 3, etc., you could use the following:

```
{=INDEX(tbl, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($S2, $B$2:$B$9)*COUNTIF($R2, $D$2:$D$9), 
ROW(tbl)-MIN(ROW(tbl))+1), U$1), COLUMN($D$1))}
```

This will copy down and across.

Comment: Thanks! See my `FOLLOW-UP` edit to the question above so hopefully I can get your solution to work!

Comment: OK, first it looks like your `COUNTIF()` params are reversed. Secondly, I'm not following how the formula works. The condition for the `IF()` statement is the result of the two `COUNTIF()` statements being multiplied together, which results in an integer (thus, `TRUE` always)...

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to update! I actually was working on the solution I just posted before I saw this. Like I said, I'm confident your solution is also viable!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for pivot tables and go to special. You need to add an ID # column though. Here is one way you could do it:

[image: PivotTableSolution1]

[image: PivotTableSolution2]

Then once the blanks are selected using go to special you just need to delete them and shift cells left.
[image: PivotTableSolution3]

Good Luck.

Comment: I did the same thing first!  Took no time at all to set up and use.

Comment: Yea, I just thought I would throw this out there because it was the easiest way to do it for me personally. We'll see if he prefers a formula answer(like yours) - it seems like he did in his question.