# extracting multiple text in different cells into one cell

Tags: excel

I need assistance in seeing if there’s a formula to the below excel dilemma:
(Note - dash lines are used as separators indicating different column)

Currently I have a spread sheet with the below data: 2 columns (A--B)

Abby -- apple
Abby -- orange
Abby -- lime
Bob  -- orange
Bob  -- apple
Carol-- lime
Carol-- orange
David-- apple

Is there  a formula that tells Excel to pick up identical text in Column A and consolidate the respective Column B items into one Cell in Column C? : please find below the end result that I’m after:

Abby -- apple ---- apple orange lime
Abby -- orange
Abby -- lime
Bob  -- orange ---- orange apple
Bob  -- apple
Carol-- lime  ---- lime orange
Carol-- orange
David-- apple  ---- apple

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Kit

Comment: Does it have to be a formula?  How about a little programming? :)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to modify the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096573/excel-return-values-from-multiple-matching-rows/12119206#12119206) to fit your needs. It's more complex than what you need since you are only matching on a single column instead of two or more, but the underlying concept is actually the same.