# Create a table that shows selected rows from another sheet

Tags: excel, select, excel-formula

I have an Excel workbook with a sheet looking something like this:

```
Apple    |    15    |    Bob
Banana   |    20    |    Tim
Apple    |    19    |    Mary
Banana   |    25    |    Kate
```

I want to create another sheet that only shows rows from the first sheet that have "Apple" in the first column:

```
Apple    |    15    |    Bob
Apple    |    19    |    Mary
```

In a sense this is analogous to an SQL SELECT query, where we select all entries in the first table (sheet) that have a given value.

The catch is that I don't want to have to constantly maintain the second sheet. If I change the first sheet—for example, change "Apple" in the first row to "Grape"—I want the second sheet to automatically update so that it only shows "Apple" rows—in that example, only the "Mary" row would now be shown.

This would seem to be a commonly useful feature. Is it possible to do this without using Visual Basic scripting?

Comment: You can either use a pivot table in the second sheet or an array formula. Both solutions are shown in [Excel: return values from multiple matching rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096573/excel-return-values-from-multiple-matching-rows)

Comment: @OldPeculier Is there any reason answer is not accepted ?

Comment: @Santosh I haven't tested it. I can't because I'm on Mac Excel 2008 and can't use VBA (it turns out). So I need non-VBA responses only. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a complex non-array standard formula but you will have to fill a few rows beyond what you initially return in order to automatically compensate for future additions/deletions/modifications.

[image: List First, Second, Third rows with criteria]

I've put the target table on the same worksheet as the source table to save space for this sample but I've adjusted the cell range references in the formula(s) so that you can easily tell which is which.

Start by typing *Apple* into E4 then put this formula into F4.

```
=IF(LEN($E4), IFERROR(INDEX('first sheet'!B$1:B$999, SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$999)+('first sheet'!$A$1:$A$999<>$E4)*1E+99, , ), ROW(1:1))), ""), "")
```

Fill that right to G4 then fill F4:G4 down one row to F5:G5. Put this formula into E5.

```
=IF(COUNTIF('first sheet'!A:A, E4)>(COUNTIF(E$4:E4, E4)), E4, "")
```

Now fill E5:G5 down to catch all possible return (plus a few rows) from the source worksheet.

Typing any new fruit value into E4 will instantly change the nature of the returned data.

The calculations on this are not horrifically complex and the cell ranges pointing to the source data should easily be able to handle a few thousand rows but you will start to see calculation lag as the source data grows.

I have seen some users use a conditional formatting check against a [COUNTIF](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) or [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED) to make sure that they are collecting all of the possible rows. This would indicate when there are not enough formulas to capture all of the results. Implementing something like that is strictly up to the user. Post back with specifics if that is something you would want to put to use.

I've put that sample workbook (with differrent source and target worksheets) on my Office Cast here: [Excel_Formula_to_Mimic_SQL_Query.xlsx](https://dd.edog.officeapps.live.com/d/excel-formula-to-mimic-sql-query_DKHIZJVVpVoN1kAAQEDRwJA%7eM6ca7a073-f15a-38a5-79a2-bda619e06ac7).

Comment: I'd be interrested in a similar solution but instead that shows (on another sheet, for exemple) what is the result of the filterings done on the reference sheet. ex: ref sheet has 10000 lines, but after a few columns filtering, it's now down to 2000 lines displayed. I'd like to have the 2nd sheet habe 2000 values in rows 2-2001, showing everything now displayed in sheet 1 (ie, the result of all the filterings) : seems there is a way from your solution but I struggle to grok it.  TLDR: a way to have sheet2 display what would be a manual "copy all from sheet1" , when sheet1 has been filtered

Answer (score 0):

Copy the below code to sheet1 code section.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:A" & lastRow)

    Sheets("sheet2").Cells.Clear
    If Not Intersect(rng, Target) Is Nothing And Target.Value <> "" Then
        For Each cell In rng
            If Trim(LCase(cell.Value)) = Trim(LCase(Range("A1"))) Then
                With Sheets("sheet2")
                    cell.Resize(, 3).Copy .Cells(.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)
                End With
            End If
        Next
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```