# A function that will lookup a reference

Tags: excel

Before I get started thanks for taking your time and helping.

This is what my worksheet looks like:

```
  Row #  B    C          D     E    F    
   2     1   Product 1  B2   B3    B4    
   3     2          
   4     6
   5     1   Product 2  B5    B6
   6     5
   7     4   Product 3  B7
```

I was trying to follow this formula: (The best answer one or green check mark) [return values from multiple matching rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096573/excel-return-values-from-multiple-matching-rows)

I got all the way to the `=IFERROR(INDIRECT(lookups!H5),"")` but can not get this to work.

What I am tying to do is order the numbers in Column B to go to the right of the product. Which I was able to get the column it is in (B) and the row number it is in (B2). I would like to change the value (B2) to the number that is there.

I would like it to look like this:

```
Row #  C            D    E   F  
 2     Product 1    1    2   6
 3
 4
 5     Product 2    1    5
 6
 7     Product 3    4
```

If someone could help explain this to me or find a better way that would be great.

Comment: Have you tried putting the sheet name in single quotes? Why do you even have it on there if this is all on the same sheet?

Comment: Can you show me what you mean by "sheet name in single quotes"?

Comment: =IFERROR(INDIRECT('lookups'!H5),"")

Comment: Also, INDIRECT does not like to work with actual cell references. It's looking for strings. =IFERROR(INDIRECT(lookups!H5),"") will always return "" because INDIRECT(lookups!H5) will always return an error because lookups!H5 is not in quotes, indicating it is a string value.

Comment: I was using the formula that guy had. Thanks for the help

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not sure how that even works for him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is to happen to columnB but if you replace `B` with `"="B` throughout columns D:F then select each of these in turn and apply Text to Columns with Tab as the delimiter the 'cell references' convert to formulae referring to the values in B. If you want to delete columnB copy D:F and Paste Special, Values over the top.

Comment: Thank you, something so simple that I just couldn't wrap my head around.