# Excel building table with two instances

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

So im building a table to show people that are assigned to work.

I build the names using a list thats stored in a datasheet named lists then depending on whether or not they've got a flag set to one in the master table the row is added to the assigned table.

However I am running into a problem I cannot seem to fix in that a person may be assigned to two projects.There is only one instance of their name in the assigned table and the search only returns the first row found in the master table. Meaning that if someone is assigned to two projects I can only see one in my assigned table.

Is there anyway I can get the list to show all of the projects one user is assigned to? I was thinking about populating the names from the master sheet where the flag is set to 1 would this work?

Any insight would be much appreciated, Thanks in advance

EDIT:

- Assigned table contains a row relating to a name from master table where flag=1
- Master table could have two instances of same name with flag=1
- Using Match and index only returns first instance of flag=1 found
- Therefore if a person is assigned to two projects only one will show as there is only one row with there name

At the moment I'm using this formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Master Data'!$D$2:$D$153,MATCH(1,(B23='Master Data'!$J$2:$J$153)*('Master Data'!$W$2:$W$153=1),FALSE)),"")
```

- Where D = Data required
- B23= persons name in assigned
- J = persons name in master
- W = flag for assigned

Comment: Your question is confusing.  You state that "theres only one entry of there name in the original table" yet you also state there are duplicates if someone is on multiple projects.  Where are these duplicates?   You need to be more concise, use the actual names of the Tabs, and write your question like you would write code.  That said, there are all sorts of existing answers about getting subsequent matches when using VLOOKUP and MATCH.  Just google search.  A place to start is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096573/return-values-from-multiple-matching-rows

Comment: Sorry I know its very confusing have tried to tidy it up a little bit